# PhantomJS not logging all errors listed in browser console

Tags: javascript, error-handling, phantomjs

When I go back and forth between the browser console and the error output on PhantomJS, I see discrepancies between the two.  In particular jquery.js uncaught errors are not picked up in my PhantomJS console.log.

Here is my code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create(),
  system = require('system'), address


page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
  console.log("Caught on Console Message: " + msg);
};

page.onError = function(msg) {
 console.log("Caught on page.onError: " + msg);
};

phantom.onError = function(msg) {
 console.log("Caught on phantom.onError: " + msg);
 trace.forEach(function(item) {
    console.log(' ', item.file, ":", item.line);
 });
};

page.onResourceError = function(resourceError) {
  console.log('Unable to load resource (#' + resourceError.id + 'URL:' + resourceError.url + ')');
  console.log('Error code: ' + resourceError.errorCode + '. Description: ' + resourceError.errorString);
};

page.onAlert = function (msg) {
    console.log("Caught on Alert: " + msg);
};

if (system.args.length === 1) {
  console.log('Usage: someScript <some URL>');
  phantom.exit();
}

address = system.args[1];

try {
    page.open(address, function(status) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("I will exit now");
            phantom.exit();
        },10000);
    }); 
} catch (err) {
    console.log("Exception caught: " + err);
}
```

cnn.com has a ton of output in the console.   I mostly miss uncaught Errors.

Comment: You have added all the useful event handlers. It is either the bug in PhantomJS 2.x at play or the errors aren't actually thrown in PhantomJS. I don't think there is a way to distinguish the two possibilities.

Comment: I am starting to think that.  I noticed I was not getting the same fatal errors across all browsers which makes your comment very plausible.   Really bummed about that.

Comment: Try to run it with PhantomJS 1.9.8.